# How to fix Google Maps Platform rejected your request. Invalid request. Unexpected parameter 'amp%3Bkey'

Tags: angular, iframe

angular error

> Google Maps Platform rejected your request. Invalid request.
>   Unexpected parameter 'amp%3Bkey'.

in console

> GET
>   https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=19.499201,77.656332&key=APIKEY
>   400

HTML code

```
<iframe width="100%" height="150" frameborder="0" style="border:0" [src]="location(details)"></iframe>
```

TS code

```
location(details:any){
    let location = `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=${details.longitude},${details.latitude}&amp;key=<apiKey>`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(location);
}
```

I am facing the issue with

> bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl function which converts the string ','
>   comma to '%3B'

.

Answer (score 0):

in the above example, I was using iframe source address with ResourceUrl sanitizer, which results in the conversion of string ',' to '%3B' somehow. Which is not working at the end. 
So I used the alternate way that takes sanitize HTML from ts file as below.

HTML

```
<div class="map-box" [innerHtml]="Location(Details) | safe: 'html'">
```

TS

```
Location(details:any){
        let locationIframe = `<iframe width="100%" height="150" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=${details.longitude},${details.latitude}&amp;key=${this.gmapApiKey}" > </iframe>`;
        return locationIframe;
    }
```

PIPE -> safe: 'html'

```
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
```